# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource to specific method

Tags: angular, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I run my solution in webApi net.core, and angular , and iis.
I success to pass login function(get). but update function (post), I get error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/Test/UpdateId' from origin 
'http://localhost:3400' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

localhost:8080 - i get from IIS server.
localhost:3400 - i get from angular.

my controller:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(PermissionFilter), Arguments = new object[] { Modules.Employees, Permissions.Edit, Permissions.Add })]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Test/UpdateId")]
public ActionResult<IdModel> UpdateId([FromBody]IdModel idModel)
    { //some code...
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
"AllowSpecificOrigin": "http://localhost:3400"

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
     services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowSpecificOrigin"))
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
            app.UseAuthentication();
      
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {      
            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.Use((corsContext, next) =>
                            {
                            corsContext.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                                return next.Invoke();
                            });

            app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var feature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = feature.Error;
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { hasError = true, message = exception.Message });
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }));
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var feature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = feature.Error;

                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { hasError = true, message = exception.Message });
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }));

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            });
        }
```

my angular, and run : npx ng serve --open --port 3400

```
UpdateEmployee(idModel): any {
return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/Test/UpdateId', idModel);
```

}

how fix this error? maybe it is IIS?

thank.

Comment: here is already an answer to your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 1):

> I run my solution in webapi .core, and angular, and iis when I try run
> my function, I get error .No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource to specific method

Based on your error description it has clearly appeared that, your request has not been matched because your CORS defination is `"AllowSpecificOrigin": "http://localhost:3400"` but your request has been sent from `http://localhost:8080` that might causing the issue.

In addition, couple of way out there in order to get rid of above error.

**1.** Configure CORS hearder in http Request:

You can set request header from your angular request to overcome the error. You can do as following:

```
const headers = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'};
```

Full Request should be like below:

```
this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/Test/UpdateId', idModel, {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})
```

**Note:** You check more details here [how to add CORS header in angular request](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)..

**2.** Middleware Order:

In correct middleware order can also cause above exception where CORS configuration might not work as expected. We should use `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization` and midddleware order should as following:

[image]

**Note:** Please double [check the CORS middleware order here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware)

**3.** Server Strict Invoke:

If above steps doesn't work accordingly and the problem still recurrent you could then implement server CORS header invocation. You can do that as following:

```
app.Use((corsContext, next) =>
            {
                corsContext.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
                return next.Invoke();
            });
```

**Note:** If you still want to know more details on the issue you could [check the additional resource here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-in-iis)

Comment: I try option: 1,3 but it is not work. how I write UseRouting, funtion, it is unknow in my code? I have app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });

Comment: Your CORS should place in between Routing and Authentication middleware. app.UseMvc shouldn't impact CORS. By the way, what's your asp.net core version?

Comment: my asp.net core version is 2.2. I still don't succses.

Comment: Thank you mate, you helped me with the middlewares order info.

Comment: Glad to know that it was helpful for you.